# Non-region of interest with Mat Image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mat, roi

I want to get features from non-region of interest area. I know how to define ROI in `Mat` format, however, I also need the rest of the area for negative image features.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the mask to define any region you want to get features. However, it requires the called function to support mask.

For example:

```
void ORB::operator()(InputArray image, InputArray mask, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, OutputArray descriptors, bool useProvidedKeypoints=false ) const

mask – The operation mask.
```

---

If the functions do not support mask. There are two tricks to get the features in non-ROI:

1. Get the features of whole image, then filter the result manually.
2. Split the non-ROI into ROI's (as following), then pass the ROI's into the function.

For example:

```
|-----------------|
|        1        |
|----|-------|----|
| 2  |       |  3 |
|----|-------|----|
|        4        |
|-----------------|
```

Comment: This might work better because when I apply a mask, the ROI will be black and this causes irrelevant keypoints on the edges of ROI.